# Getting Dictionary<string,string> from List<Control>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-3.0, dictionary

I want a dictionary containing the names and text of all controls. Is it possible with predefined framework methods/LINQ/colection initializers or do I have to make a loop and add all entries by myself?

This gives me an error message:

```
List<Control> controls;
// .. initialize list ..
controls.ToDictionary((Control child,string k)=>new KeyValuePair<string,string>(child.Name, child.Text));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call should be like this:

```
controls.ToDictionary(
    c => c.Name,       // Key selector
    c => c.Text);      // Element selector.
```

Answer (score 2):

It should probably look something like this:

```
controls.ToDictionary(c => c.Name, c => c.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dictionary<String, String> myControls = ((from Control c in Controls select c).ToDictionary(c => c.Name, c => c.Text))
```